# Create a button like monaca debugger button

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I want to create a button like this to my application.Please  someone help me to do this

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it by using the `<ons-speed-dial>` element of Onsen UI: https://tutorial.onsen.io/?framework=vanilla&category=reference&module=speed-dial

If you want your buttons to be scattered like in the Debugger, then after choosing the direction of the  `<ons-speed-dial>`, add a margin to each of the `<ons-speed-dial-item>` to place them where you want them to be.